# KeyError al crear diccionario, python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de armar una lista como diccionario, tomando la primera posición como llave, pero este solo me hace el recorrido una vez

Estos son los datos de mi lista al recorrerla:

```
('ID_CLIENTE', 'ID_ASESOR', 'ASESOR')
('123456', '987654', 'DIANA LIZETH RODRIGUEZ')
('369852', '159263', 'JUAN CAMILO BERMUDEZ')
```

lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

```
(dicUnica,{'ID_CLIENTE': [ID_ASESOR, ASESOR],'123456': ['987654', 'DIANA LIZETH RODRIGUEZ'], '369852': ['159263', 'JUAN CAMILO BERMUDEZ']})
```

En el momento solo he conseguido que me recorra una sola vez la lista, arrojandome este resultado:

{'369852': ['159263', 'JUAN CAMILO BERMUDEZ']}

Mi código:

```
for row in ResUnica:
    ID_CLIENTE = row[0]
    ID_ASESOR = row[1]
    ASESOR = row[2]      
    dicUnica = {ID_CLIENTE:[ID_ASESOR,ASESOR]}

print(dicUnica)
```

Comment: Primero tienes que crear la entrada en el diccionario con `dicUnica[ID_CLIENTE]=[]`. Eso inicializa la entrada con una lista vacia. Por supuesto, solo una vez por cliente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución más compacta:

```
dicUnica = {id_cliente: resto for id_cliente, *resto in ResUnica}
```

En la comprensión usamos `*resto` para recibir en una lista todos los elementos de la fila de entrada después de la id_cliente.

**Demo**

```
ResUnica = [('ID_CLIENTE', 'ID_ASESOR', 'ASESOR'),
('123456', '987654', 'DIANA LIZETH RODRIGUEZ'),
('369852', '159263', 'JUAN CAMILO BERMUDEZ')]

dicUnica = {id_cliente: resto for id_cliente, *resto in ResUnica}

print(dicUnica)
```

produce:

```
{'ID_CLIENTE': ['ID_ASESOR', 'ASESOR'], '123456': ['987654', 'DIANA LIZETH RODRIGUEZ'], '369852': ['159263', 'JUAN CAMILO BERMUDEZ']}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

ya logre realizarlo, con el metodo update, quedando de esta manera:

```
dicUnica = {'A':1}
for row in ResUnica:
    ID_CLIENTE = row[0]
    ID_ASESOR = row[1]
    ASESOR = row[2]
    
    key, value = ID_CLIENTE, [ID_ASESOR,ASESOR]
    dicUnica.update({key: value})
```